# Infinite loop found on line 0

Tags: javascript, html, infinite-loop

I am trying to make a tic-tac-toe game, but in Codepen my Javascript gives me an error saying "Infinite loop found on line 0. The line number is approximated so look carefully." Here is the pen

See the Pen [Tic-Tac-Toe](http://codepen.io/spacegeek224/pen/jAzokG/) by Maris ([@spacegeek224](http://codepen.io/spacegeek224)) on [CodePen](http://codepen.io).

and here is my JS:

```
(function() {
  var PLAYERS = ['X','O'];
  var TURN = PLAYERS[0];
  var BOARD = [new Array(3),new Array(3),new Array(3)];

  function togglePlayer() {
    TURN = (TURN == PLAYERS[0]) ? PLAYERS[1] : PLAYERS[0];
  }

  $('.square').click(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).attr('data-p')) {

    } else {
      $(e.target).attr('data-p',TURN).text(TURN);

      BOARD[$(e.target).attr('data-y')][$(e.target).attr('data-x')] = TURN;
      if (checkWin(BOARD)) {
        $('.turn').attr('data-p',checkWin(BOARD)).text(checkWin(BOARD) + " wins!");
        $('.square:not([data-p])').attr('data-p',true);
      }
      else {
        togglePlayer();
        $('.turn').attr('data-p',TURN).text(TURN+"\'s turn");
      }    
    }
  });

  function checkWin(board) {
    for (var i = 0;i<3;i++) {
      if (board [0][i] !== undefined) 
        if (board[0][i]==board[1][i] && board[1][i] == board[2][i])
          return board[0][i];
      else if (board [i][0] !== undefined) 
        if (board[i][0]==board[i][1] && board[i][1] == board[i][2])
          return board[i][0];
      else if (board[1][1] !== undefined)
        if (board[0][0] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][2])
           return board[1][1];
        else if (board[0][2] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][0])
           return board[1][1];
    }
    return false;
  }

  $('.container').on('dblclick',function() {
    $('.square').removeAttr('data-p').text('');
    BOARD = [new Array(3),new Array(3),new Array(3)];
    TURN = PLAYERS[0];
    $('.turn').attr('data-p',TURN).text(TURN+"\'s turn");
  });



})();
```

Comment: did you try **not** in codepen? (it's irrelevant to the question where did you try the code because if there's a problem with the code it won't run anywhere anyway)

Comment: btw, you should save the result of `checkWin` instead of calling the function everywhere again and again. you are constantly repeating code everywhere. try to not do that...

Comment: The check win logic also doesn't work anyway

Comment: You shouldn't be checking your diagonals inside that for loop. They're not dependent on the counter. And use a single return.

Comment: @spacegeek224 when i ran the CodePen i don't see the error you are talking about.

Comment: I ran in CodePen and Fiddle and I'm getting 0 errors.

Comment: I figured out the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, and i cant believe I didn't see this before. In the checkWin function I should have put `if` instead of `if else` inside the for loop.